# nested async and sync in Julia

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, macros, julia, synchronization

I want to do multi Task (A,B) pairs which have no connections with each other. Each Task A include multi Task a. Task A has to be done before B start in the same one (A,B) pair. So it's like

```
@async for loop do multi (A,B)s
    @sync do one (A,B)
        @async for loop do Task A
            do Task a
        do Task B
```

how can I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
b = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
ta = @async for i in range(1, length(b))
    a = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
    @async for j in range(1, length(a)) # task A
        a[j] = "hello "
        sleep(1) # task a
    end

    #task B
    b[i] = prod(a) * "world!"
    sleep(1)

end
@time wait(ta)
```

fail: Task B does not wait for task A in the same pair.

```
b = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
ta = @async for i in range(1, length(b))
    a = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
    for j in range(1, length(a)) # task A
        @async begin
            a[j] = "hello "
            sleep(1) # task a
        end
    end

    #task B
    b[i] = prod(a) * "world!"
    sleep(1)

end
@time wait(ta)
```

fail: Task B does not wait for task A in the same pair.

```
b = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
ta = @async for i in range(1, length(b))
    a = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
    taA= @async for j in range(1, length(a)) # task A
        a[j] = "hello "
        sleep(1) # task a
    end
    wait(taA)

    #task B
    b[i] = prod(a) * "world!"
    sleep(1)

end
@time wait(ta)
```

fail: multi (A,B) pairs not async to each other.

```
b = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
ta = @async for i in range(1, length(b))
    a = Vector{String}(undef, 6)
    taA = @async for j in range(1, length(a)) # task A
        a[j] = "hello "
        sleep(1) # task a
    end

    while !istaskdone(taA)
        sleep(0.5)
    end

    b[i] = prod(a) * "world!"
    sleep(1)

end
@time wait(ta)
```

fail: multi (A,B) pairs not async to each other.

Comment: "Task A has to be done before B start in the same one (A,B) pair." That sounds like they're of the same length, since each A task has to be performed before its corresponding B task. But you're taking their lengths separately in the code. Are the list of A tasks and the list of B tasks of the same length?

Comment: The Lengths of A and B are the same but A has multi little a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you want to have:

```
@sync for (A, B) in ABs
           @async begin
               @sync for a in A
                   @async do_task_A(a)
               end
               do_task_B(B)
           end
       end
```

For an example consider the function:

```
function do_task(t, x)
   sleep(1/x)
   println("Done $t : $x")
   flush(stdout)
end
```

Lets run it!

```
julia> @time @sync for (A, B) in [([1,2], 100), ([3,4], 101),([5,6], 102)]
           @async begin
               @sync for a in A
                   @async do_task(:A, a)
               end
               do_task(:B, B)
           end
       end
Done A : 6
Done A : 5
Done B : 102
Done A : 4
Done A : 3
Done B : 101
Done A : 2
Done A : 1
Done B : 100
  1.079950 seconds (20.25 k allocations: 1020.699 KiB, 3.52% compilation time)
```

You can see that tasks got executed asynchronously exactly in the order you requested.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

All the answer from @Przemyslaw Szufel, I just sum it up as a note:

```
@sync for loop do task A
    @async do task(a)

do task(B)
```

then Task B will wait until Task A finishes. And Multi Task a in Task A will be async to each other.

It is the building block for do multi Task a and then do Task B.

if you want to nest it, then just:

```
@sync for loop do Task (A,B)
    @async begin
        @sync for loop do task A
            @async do task(a)

        do task(B)
    end

do task C
```

use the `@sync` macro before the for loop and then use the `@async` macro to wrap the content in the for loop. Then the multi little tasks in the for loop will run async to each other, but the code after the for loop will wait until the for loop finishes.

example code from @Przemyslaw Szufel

```
function do_task(t, x)
    println("start $t : $x")
    flush(stdout)
    sleep(1 / x)
    println("Done $t : $x")
    flush(stdout)
end

@time @sync for (A, B) in [([1, 2], 100), ([3, 4], 101), ([5, 6], 102)]
    @async begin
        @sync for a in A
            @async do_task(:A, a)
        end
        do_task(:B, B)
    end
end
```